# Зачем использовать пустой массив,помимо использования метода split&

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, методы

В Данной задаче не понятно зачем создавать в данном пункте  var classes = obj.className ? obj.className.split(' ') : [];   пустой массив? Где-то было утверждение,что в целях наличия пустой строки в свойстве объекта,т.к по заданию указано,что бы функция не добавляла лишних пробелов.`введите сюда код`

В объекте есть свойство className, которое содержит список «классов» – слов, разделенных пробелом:

var obj = {
  className: 'open menu'
}
Создайте функцию addClass(obj, cls), которая добавляет в список класс cls, но только если его там еще нет:

```
addClass(obj, 'new'); // obj.className='open menu new'
addClass(obj, 'open'); // без изменений (класс уже существует)
addClass(obj, 'me'); // obj.className='open menu new me'

alert( obj.className ); // "open menu new me"
P.S. Ваша функция не должна добавлять лишних пробелов.

function addClass(obj, cls) {
  var classes = obj.className ? obj.className.split(' ') : [];

  for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    if (classes[i] == cls) return; 
  }

  classes.push(cls); // добавить

  obj.className = classes.join(' '); 
}

var obj = {
  className: 'open menu'
};

addClass(obj, 'new');
addClass(obj, 'open');
addClass(obj, 'me');
alert(obj.className) // open menu new me
```

Comment: Затем, что при пустом className `''.split(' ')` создаст непустой массив, который в данном случае нафиг не нужен

Comment: Т.е. при использовании пробела в качестве разделителя,при пустом свойстве создаётся массив с элементом в виде пустой строки, я правильно понял?

Comment: Почти, для любого разделителя split пустой строки создаст непустой массив с пустой строкой внутри